# How to add count of records to group in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have the following line of code that takes records from my database and creates a new consolidated record:

```
@opportunities = @unpublished_reports.group(:assigned_user_id, :probability, :reporting_date).
                                select("assigned_user_id, 
                                SUM(amount) AS amount,
                                SUM(amount_tp) AS amount_tp,
                                probability AS probability,
                                reporting_date AS reporting_date")
```

This gives me an array like so (I just show the first object of the array):

```
[#<Opportunity id: nil, assigned_user_id: "1234", amount: 1101650, amount_tp: 1548964, probability: 0, reporting_date: "2017-08-25">]
```

What I want to do now is to include in this array also the count of all these records. I tried something like this:

```
@opportunities = @unpublished_reports.group(:assigned_user_id, :probability, :reporting_date).
                                select("assigned_user_id, 
                                SUM(amount) AS amount,
                                SUM(amount_tp) AS amount_tp,
                                probability AS probability,
                                reporting_date AS reporting_date,
                                COUNT(assigned_user_id) AS number_of_records")
```

However, this does not work - my array looks still the same. How to do it?
I'm using postgresql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`number_of_records` is selected as you're expecting; it's just not displayed in the console output:

```
[#<Opportunity id: nil, assigned_user_id: "1234", amount: 1101650, amount_tp: 1548964, probability: 0, reporting_date: "2017-08-25">]
```

Only the columns that are persisted in the table are displayed in this output, since you have `amount`, `amount_tp`, etc... columns, here they are.

If you try in the console `@opportunities.last.number_of_records` you'll receive the expected result. Just call `number_of_records` on the model as if there is such a method.